# Android sqlite write ahead logging notworking

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, wal

I am using SQLiteOpenHelper in Android with calling `setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true);`

basically I do a bunch of network syncs (each one in their own thread and they call the next one in their `onPostExecute`) each time so I want to put all of them in a Transaction, so I call `beginTransactionNonExclusive()` and after finishing all the job I `setTransactionSuccessful()` and in finally block I call `endTransaction()'

the problem though, is in some of my syncs I need to read some rows from db and post them to server so I have to call `database.rawQuery(queryString, null);` with a `select` as queryString. as soon as my code reaches here I start getting following in the logcat:

```
The connection pool for database '+data+data_package_db_file' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 3103 (AsyncTask #4) with flags 0x2 for 4.0010004 seconds.
Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 1 available.
```

isn't this what `setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled` is for?

perhaps I should explain that executing select query in the main thread (which started the transaction) has no problem but select from another thread causes the scene !

Comment: Are trying to use the same connection from multiple threads?

Comment: ofcourse, that is what `setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled` is for, isn't it?

Comment: No. WAL is a mechanism that allow more concurrency between multiple connections.

Comment: so there is no way to make multiple connections from different threads ?!?!?!?!

Comment: When you have multiple threads, use multiple connections.

Comment: From the docs: `This method enables parallel execution of queries from multiple threads on the same database. It does this by opening multiple connections to the database and using a different database connection for each query.` When enabled it creates multiple connections right? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#enablewriteaheadlogging